# Is it possible to project this matrix to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to project a matrix $M$ to zero if it does not have zero eigenvectors? For instance, I've been trying to project the matrix:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & \sqrt{2} \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
to zero, but I couldn't find a way to do it. After some calculations, I noticed that it has only nonzero eigenvalues. Does this make the projection impossible?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "project to zero?" Certainly, if you multiply $M$ by the zero matrix you get zero matrix back?

Comment: I'd like some projection matrix $P$ such that $PMP = 0$ (or, sufficiently, $PM = MP = 0$. The trivial projection (multiply by zero) is not interesting to me.

Comment: Can you find a projection matrix $P_{ik}$ such that $P_{ik}M$ or $MP_{ik}$ have the $(i,k)$ entry of $M$ zeroed out?

Comment: That was more or less what I've been trying to do, but I couldnt make any progress. I was trying to use the fact that $M$ is block-diagonal and the matrices on the diagonal are inverse to each other.

Comment: @gt6989b although I already have my answer, I got interested about your comment. Is this projection matrix $P_{ik}$ easy to construct? Is it a known matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is symmetric, then such a projection does not exist if all eigenvalues of $M$ are positive or all eigenvalues of $M$ are negative.

In all other cases, such a projection exists. For your particular example, consider
$$
P = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0}.
$$

Comment: Very interesting answer. I did not know about this property about symmetry. I thought the only way to project a given matrix to zero was if it has some zero eigenvalue. Thank you so much!

Comment: @InMathweTrust Glad to help. Notably, we can only attain $MP = 0$ or $PM = 0$ for a non-trivial projection if all eigenvalues of $M$ are non-zero.

Comment: Ben, one little curiosity. I noticed that your example is not unique; I was able to construct at least two more projections to zero after you posted your answer. However, all these examples have zero determinant and are not inversible. Does it always occur for projection matrices?

Comment: @InMathweTrust If $P$ is a projection matrix (i.e. $P$ is symmetric and $P^2 = P$), then $P$ can only have a non-zero determinant if $P$ is the identity matrix.